# can someone explain code __ for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "?"')

Tags: batch-file

i want to pass 3 file names(

```
C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file1
C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file2
C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file3
```

) to the below code

```
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "?"') do svn add "%%i"
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

`svn status %1 ^| find "?"` will filter the output of `svn status` command (with the first argument passed) and will show the lines that contain "?".Pipe is escaped because the command is invoked from a for loop.

`for /f` processes an output of a command . "tokens=2*" means get the second word and everything after will count as the third word. The words are accessed with alphabetically ordered tokens - in this case `%%i` so `svn add "%%i"` will get the second word from the output of the command will replaces in in the `svn add`

To process the three files you can nest two for loops:

```
for %%# in(C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file1 C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file2 C:\Users\c_skanik\Desktop\dir\file3) do (
 for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('svn status %%# ^| find "?"') do svn add "%%i"

)
```

Comment: Thank you npocmaka for great explanation.

my requirement is 

1. Need to search all .exe files in a directory recursively(for this i am uisng for loop as __ "" for /r %%i in (*.exe) do echo %%i ""
2. On the output we got from above for loop we need to pass to the below for loops

for ___%%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "?"') do svn add "%%i"
for ___ %%i in ('svn status %1 ^| find "!"') do svn delete "%%i"
svn commit -m "Automatic commit" %1

how can i do this,